# show() and hide() functions not working in jQuery 1.11.1

Tags: jquery

```
  <!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <a href="#" id='hide_show'>Hide</a>
    <div id='message' style='font-size:14px; padding:10px; width:300px; border:1px solid red; margin-top:20px;'>Under Direction, click Up to search from the current cursor position to the top of the document, or click Down to search from the cursor position to the bottom of the document. Under Direction, click Up to search from the current cursor position to the top of the document, or click Down to search from the cursor position to the bottom of the document.Under Direction, click Up to search from the current cursor position to the top of the document, or click Down to search from the cursor position to the bottom of the document.</div>


    <script src='js/jquery.js'></script>
    <script src='js/jquery_ui.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#hide_show').toggle(function() {
                $('#hide_show').text('Show');
                $('#message').hide();
            }, function() {
                $('#hide_show').text('Hide');
                $('#message').show();
            });

        });
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

The above code not giving the actual result...when I am checking in browser the link 'Hide' is suddenly disappearing...can some body help me out on this...and also I am not getting any errors in console.

Comment: This particular format of [toggle was removed](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed) in jQuery 1.9

Comment: would be great if people put a little more effort in googling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This particular format of [toggle was removed](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed) in jQuery 1.9

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#hide_show').click(function () {
        $('#hide_show').text(function (i, text) {
            return $.trim(text) == 'Hide' ? 'Show' : 'Hide'
        });
        $('#message').toggle();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y8883/)